# ReferenceError: config is not defined

Tags: truffle-compile

require("babel-register");
require("babel-polyfill");
require("dotenv"),config();

module.exports = {
   networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7547,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  },
  contracts_directory: './source/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I keep getting config not defined using Truffle Compile  v5.0.26 (core: 5.0.26)
Node v9.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have a typo, a comma should be a full stop.

Your Truffle config `truffle-config.js` has `require("dotenv"),config();` when it should be `require('dotenv').config();`